# get items unique for a list using joins in ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This is my query

```
SELECT lists.id, items.id FROM `lists` LEFT JOIN items ON lists.id = items.list_id
```

I have three lists and list 1 has three items
then in rails it gives me three tables of the form

```
**list1  list1  list1**         
item1  item1  item1
item2  item2  item2
item3  item3  item3
```

That means it is looping according to the number of items
Is there any way in rails that i can create an array in erb file itself and can put a check for if record already exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a normal behavior of a sql join - all rows where the condition is met are returned. If a list has 5 items - you'll have 5 results where lists.id = items.list_id.

Maybe you are looking for GROUP BY?

```
lists = List.joins("LEFT JOIN items on lists.id = items.list_id").group("lists.id")
```